# Can anyone explain use of Joblet in Talend

Tags: talend

Can anyone please give me some brief description and uses of Joblet in talend.

I have tried to get the information in google but it's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

A Joblet is a specific component that replaces Job component groups. Joblets can be reused in different Jobs or several times in the same Job.

At runtime, the Joblet code is integrated into the Job code itself. No separate code is generated, the same Java class being used.

Unlike for the tRunJob component, the Joblet code is automatically included in the Job code at runtime, thus using less resources. As it uses the same context variables as the Job itself, the Joblet is easier to maintain.

To use a group of components as a standalone Job, you can use the tRunJob component. Unlike the Joblet, the tRunJob has its own context variables.

[Click here to get more about usage of it](https://help.talend.com/reader/_Qg2guINsDl6hsiB7uKWzQ/vBbjWPRmaiK5H~ZP1Vah_g)